# Custom cursor blinking when using window.history.replaceState

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using window.history.replaceState method to replace URL when navigating between sub-pages. I'm using custom cursor in my web application and when I replace current URL with new one, my custom cursor blinks (I can see it is replaced by cursor: default) for a short moment. Is there any way to prevent this or is this normal behaviour? Thank you for your answers.

Edit: tis is happening in Chrome browser, in IE11 custom cursor does not blink.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? Does this occur if you move the mouse upon url replace? This might be related to [this chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532233)

Comment: I made a simple jsfiddle (I didn't use custom cursor but you can also see problem): https://jsfiddle.net/brasxthk/ - if you move this slider cursor: pointer changes into cursor: default for a moment (Chrome)

Comment: It's not blinking for me on Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) Mac, I think it might be a chrome bug.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug to me!

I'm getting the same behavior when hovering over a normal link (with the normal "pointer" icon that you get when hovering over links.)

I filed a chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1128213

Here's a simple test case to reproduce:

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    window.history.replaceState('', '', window.location.pathname);
  },
  100
);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #3af;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me! Does your cursor flicker and/or wiggle?</a>
```

Comment: Yes, it's bug and still not fixed on February 2021 :(